# Why would I want to compile from binaries vs using sudo apt-get install

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates

I am a relatively new Linux/Ubuntu user, and I am installing the IDS, Snort.

Google returns a multitude of ways in which to do this.

Could someone summarize for me why I would want to choose either of these options to install snort, or any other software application:

1. `sudo apt-get install snort`
2. following a guide like this ([link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiw5OTD3e3MAhVIkpQKHeVUCWgQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsnort.org%2Fdocuments%2Fsnort-2-9-8-x-on-ubuntu-12-lts-and-14-lts-and-15&usg=AFQjCNHyr1lOy4F1SsqBiRKUO1V1U3ptKw&sig2=QdjX0jIamVtbwSQXLwKKOA), might be broken?) that appears to have me compiling locally from the source binaries?
3. There is also a third option, which is to use a project called Autosnort. I generally have some distrust of the idea of downloading a bunch of scripts to install software on my machine, but I have no idea if that is founded or not.

How much trust should I place in opening the terminal and running `sudo apt-get install xyzsoftwarepackage`? If I allow the `universe` and `multiverse` repositories do I need to be really quite sure of exactly what I am installing? If I only allow the `main` repository should I generally be able to feel more trustworthy?

Comment: What level of paranoia do you subscribe to?

Comment: Check the link, I can't open it.

Comment: It appears that I have fixed the link. Sorry, not sure how I posted a broken one.

Answer (score 1):

Using the official repos is making sure that the software you're installing is both tested and configured as it should be, in order to function as it should.  This does not mean that you cannot or shouldn't use several TESTED ppa's.  Most of them are quite ok to use and they are very safe.

`apt-get` installs software using the repos or ppa's as sources.  This also ensures that whenever new releases appear in those sources, your copy will also be updated during the update process.

Compiling from source should be your choice only in cases when the software you need does not exist as a precompiled package in the sources mentioned above or the precompiled versions are outdated and new ones do not exist.  Compiling from source makes you and only you responsible for that software and you should check for possible updates to that software manually.

You should also know that in order to be able to compile from source, many many more packages will have to be installed on your system, for the compiler to find them and create the compiled version.

Comment: I'd probably add to an already excellent answer that if the concern of the OP is "trust", even if a program is "open source", most people would just install the dependencies and compile it.  Few people would scrutinize what it is they are compiling to make sure the program won't cause any harm.  In the end, you have to trust the developers and/or package maintainers.  If you don't trust the people, then the method of software installation doesn't really matter...

Comment: Thanks Stormlord and Ray. My account does not allow me yet to add reputation to your comments so I wanted to express appreciation.